# ASP.Net code behind not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

when I'm doing this, it works just fine:

```
submitBtt.Text = "test";
```

in the page load function.

but, when I'm trying to use it like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="submitBtt" OnClick="submitBtt_Click" runat="server" Text=' <%# test() %>'  Width="80px" />
```

the test function is in the code behind:

```
public string test()
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

all i get is a button with no text.

tried to Google it a lot and couldn't find any answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can also check "Code Expression Builder" link in my answer also talk about viewstate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<%#` is for databinding context only. So you need to call `DataBind` on the `NamingContainer` of this control. In this case the page itself:

For example in `Page_Load`:

```
this.DataBind();
```

[Here's](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx) a quick overview over the inline asp.net tags.

I would prefer using codebehind without the inline aspx since that's confusing and also hard-wiring the view with the business logic.